# how is this conversion of int * to int& working?

Tags: c++

I recently came across this c++ example from cppinstitute and I have no idea how the conversion from int* to int& works.

the output of f2 is a pointer, however, f3 takes an int&
how is the pointer turned into a variable so that f3 can take it by reference?

to be more precise, how can we write it in 3 lines?

the main code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int f1(int *a) {
    return *a + 1;
}

int *f2(int *a) {
    return a + 1;
}

int *f3(int &a) {
    return &a + 1;
}

int main() {
    int t[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    cout << f1(f3(*f2(t)));
    return 0;
}
```

how to assign the return values and pass them like this ?

```cpp
int * a = f2(t);
int * b = f3(a);  /*some kind of conversion is hapenning here*/
int c = f1(b);

cout << c;
```

the above code won't compile and the compiler complains that `a` is an `int*` not an `int`. dereferencing `a` and passing it like `f3(*a)` will compile however won't produce the same result as the original code.

**edit**
I made a mistake f3(*a) will compile and produce the same result. thanks eerorika

Comment: I think, you might benefit for reading a good C++ book. You can find curated list here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list I recommend avoiding dubious online courses, certifications and tutorials when it comes to C++ - they are often of questionable quality.

Comment: "*how is the pointer turned into a variable*" - with `*`, as always.

Comment: "*`f3(*a)` will compile however won't produce the same result as the original code*" - I just tried it. It produces exactly the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how is the pointer turned into a variable so that f3 can take it by reference?

It is not "turned into a variable". The pointed object is accessed by indirecting through the pointer:

> ```
> f3(*f2(t))
>    ^ look at this
> ```

That is the indirection operator. When applied to a pointer, the result is a reference to the pointed object.

---

> how to assign the return values and pass them like this ?
>
> ```
> int * b = f3(a);  /*some kind of conversion is hapenning here*/
> ```
>
> the above code won't compile and the compiler complains that a is an `int*` not an `int`

You need to indirect through the pointer:

```
int * b = f3(*a);
             ^ look at this
```

---

> dereferencing `a` and passing it like `f3(*a)` will compile however won't produce the same result as the original code.

It will produce the same result as the original code.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, i'm a C coder and new to c++, in C we call the * dereference operator which i googled and is the same.

Comment: @user2679808 It's called indirection operator also in the C language. Dereference operator is another, perhaps more colloquial name for the same thing, but indirection is the standard nomenclature. See for example the section of C standard titled *Address and indirection operators* which says *The unary * operator denotes indirection*.

Answer (score 0):

The `t` variable is a pointer to the beginning of the array, so `*t == t[0] == 0`.  `f2()` accepts a pointer to an integer, and returns a pointer to the next element in the array. Since `f3()` takes a *reference* to an integer, the pointer returned from `f2()` is *dereferenced*, and then its address (i.e. the address `t+1`) is passed to `f3()`. `f3()` then returns the address of integer after the `a` argument that is passed to it by taking the address of `a` and incrementing it. Finally, `f1()` receives a pointer to an integer, dereferences it and adds 1, and then returns the resulting value.

There are no implicit conversions in the example, just a mix of passing pointers and references. It would be helpful to review a C++ book, specifically a section about references. The difference between the two is only syntactic, and can indeed be confusing to beginners. Best of luck!